# Easy database IDE

Tags: sql, database

I'm looking for an IDE or "visual editor" for some basic table manipulation.

I have a few tables, ~100K entries each. Most of them share two columns that together compose a UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY. These tables are static (they are just old record data), so no "online" or code interface is needed.

To be honest I only wish Excel or something like that could handle so many rows, since I want to perform simple tasks (e.g. erase a column, sort by column). What tool in your experienced is the most "Excel-like" for static tables?

Comment: For which database server (Oracle, SQL Server etc.) do you need this editor?

Comment: @Tony: I have some as flat-files (tab seper'), some as MySQL, and some as SQLite files. Assume it's all interchangeable. I'll go with the easiest environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Microsoft Access.

You can [import or link to external data sources](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/import-or-link-data-and-objects-HP005187610.aspx) and access has lots of tools available to work with the data.

Using this method you will be able to do the following

- View the data so that you can filter & sort the data.
- write custom queries against the data (using a visual designer or SQL).
- Add, edit and delete data (providing you have edit, delete privileges on the data source)
- Write reports using the linked data.

Also, tables in Access 2007 and upwards look very much like Excel spreadsheets and as this is in the Microsoft office suite there are plenty of tools to export the data between Access and Excel.

Comment: Does MS Access 2007 import SQLite? I couldn't find how. Moreover, it couldn't import one of my flat-files - which SQLite could... I actually want to work with Access, but it gives me a hard time.

Comment: I think Access can connect to any database that supports ODBC. It can also work with data in text files and Excel spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1):

`phpmyadmin`  imo can serve as a good visual editor for what you need (though its 'online' and needs a running webserver)

Answer (score 0):

[DBDesignerFork](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dbdesigner-fork/) is open source, free, and can reverse engineer your database to build the model.

You can then switch in to Query Mode and it will help you build queries from the table diagram.

You mention you want to be able to "erase a column, sort by column" these are two very different things. The sort is easily handled using an `OREDER BY` in your `SELECT` statements. Dropping columns can also be done in SQL using the `ALTER TABLE` command but remeber there is no easy "undo" unless you start wrapping your changes in transactions.

To sum up, you should forget the Excel comparison and learn SQL :)